# From the list of dynamically created bootstrap accordion's while click on one it open's but others not closing?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, accordion, bootstrap-accordion

My requirement is to dynamically create multiple bootstrap accordions inside a popup depends upon the number user enters.In that while click on first accordion it opens but while click on second accordion first one not closing.Kindly help me to fix this.

Html code

```
    <div class="modal-body col-ms-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
    <div class="col-ms-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <h4 class="col-ms-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 nopadding">Number of workLoad</h4> 
    <input type="text" id="myText" value="1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" class=" col-ms-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"> 
    <button class="workLoadNumber col-ms-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">Submit</button><br>
    </div>

    <div class="container col-ms-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="panel-group col-ms-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="accordion">
        <p id="demo" class="col-ms-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Js code

```
    for(var i =1 ; i<= userEnteredValue ; i++){  

    selectedNodeContent  += '<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><h4 class="panel-title">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#'+accordionBaseOpen+i+'">Collapsible Group 2</a>
    </h4></div><div id="'+accordionBaseOpen+i+'" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">Hi How are you </div>
</div>
</div>'; 
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = selectedNodeContent;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Remove the p tag and place the accordions inside parent div. 


<div class="modal-body col-ms-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
        <div class="col-ms-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <h4 class="col-ms-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 nopadding">Number of workLoad</h4> 
        <input type="text" id="myText" value="1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" class=" col-ms-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"> 
        <button class="workLoadNumber col-ms-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">Submit</button><br>
        </div>

        <div class="container col-ms-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
         <div class="panel-group col-ms-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="accordion">

        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

JS:

 for(var i =1 ; i<= userEnteredValue ; i++){  

    selectedNodeContent  += '<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><h4 class="panel-title">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#'+accordionBaseOpen+i+'">Collapsible Group 2</a>
    </h4></div><div id="'+accordionBaseOpen+i+'" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">Hi How are you </div>
</div>
</div>'; 
    }
    **document.getElementById("accordion").innerHTML = selectedNodeContent;**
```